# How to use Joins sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need to to join two tables

tbl_1

```
sno     productName     productQuantity     id
```

tbl_2

```
sno     productName     remainingQuantity   id
```

My stored proc Code is

```
@id
as
begin
select a.sno,a.productName, a.productQuantity,b.remainingQuantity
from tbl_1 a join tbl_2 b
on a.id=b.id where a.id=@id
end
```

its showing result like `tbl_1 * tbl_2`(cross-join) number of row

for e.g

if tbl_1 and tbl_2 has 2 rows its showing 4 rows

i need it in 2 rows

where i made error ? thanks

Comment: Your problem lies here: `where id=@id`. SQL doesn't know which table to look at for the `@id` variable, since it exists in both `tbl_1` and `tbl_2`. You need to alias the id there as well.

Comment: i tried but showing same result

Comment: what is relationship for id column between two table?

Comment: both the tables has same value for id

Comment: in that case distinct will get you result you want. look at the answer @valentine petkov provided.

Comment: ya i tried but same issue ...

Comment: can you show the statement you tried for distinct? or show me data from both table 2 row each..

Answer (score -1):

I think you just are not declaring the stored procedure correctly. Replace your code with:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME]  
   @id int
AS
BEGIN

    select 
          a.sno,
          a.productName, 
          a.productQuantity,
          b.remainingQuantity
    from tbl_1 a 
    inner join tbl_2 b
    on a.id=b.id 
    where a.id=@id  

END
```

And then you can execute your stored procedure as:

```
 EXEC [dbo].[STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME] @id = 123
```

To Modify the stored procedure use:

`ALTER PROCEDURE` instead of `CREATE PROCEDURE`

Comment: see my comment above  Add DISTINCT